# 502 error comes for API call one after the other

Tags: api, go, bad-gateway

I'm experiencing kind of weird error, I'm calling API (which written in golang) to get access token, that API returns the correct value for one time but if I send that API call again it returns 502 error code, then if I call that API once again it will return the correct value. this happens one after the other.

Comment: That sounds like *maybe* the API is broken but more importantly, what's your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like issue happened because of the load balancing. Normally round-robin routing policy is used in load balancing. For example, if you have two servers one request goes for the first one and other one goes for the other server. So for your question, the first request is going for the working server and other is going for the non-working server. Check whether your other servers are working properly.

Comment: Thank, this is the issue I just contact our AWS guy

Answer (score -1):

You may need to check the circulation of IP data transmission between different computers under its control.